# In what context do you define an HTTP Interceptor in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to define an interceptor to handle errors in AngularJS.

I've followed the [instructions in the AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) but can't seem to make the interceptor register correctly and I wonder whether I'm doing it in the right context:

```
var editorApp = angular.module('editorApp', ['editorAppServices'])
  .run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json'
  }
);
// ----------------------

// register an interceptor (that does nothing)
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       // do something
    },

    'response': function(response) {
       // do something
    }
  };
});
```

When I add the code above I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $httpProvider is not defined
```

Where do I do this such that $httpProvider is defined?

### Edit I have the same problem with the $provide method...

I have the same issue with things not being defined when I try the `$provide` method of registration that is specified in the docs:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
      // optional method
      'request': function(config) {
        // do something on success
        return config;
      }
    //...
}
```

The console shows this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $provide is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To register an interceptor use the `config()` function of your AngularJS application like this:

```
editorApp.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push(
         // ... function to register as an interceptor
     );
}]);
```

You have to declare that this function should have an instance of `$httpProvider` injected - this is what the first string parameter of `config()` does.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your app config, inject `$httpProvider`, it's typically where I register my interceptors:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider') {
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function ($q) {
             return {
                     'request': function (config) {
                       //do stuff
                      return config || $q.when(config);
                    },
                     'requestError': function (rejection) {
                      return $q.reject(rejection);
                    },
                     'response': function (response) {
                      return response || $q.when(response);
                    },
                     'responseError': function (rejection) {
                      if (rejection.status == "401") {
                          console.log("no permission");
                      }
                      return $q.reject(rejection);
              }
      };
});
```