# mean stack login error: no token provided

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

**Background**: I am creating an app using node/express as my backend, mongo as the database, and angular as the front end.  I am using jsonwebtoken to authenticate the user. Once the user logs in, a token is stored in the local storage, which is used to authenticate all requests. After the user logs in,
the name and username is retrieved via `Auth.getUser()`, which is an angular factory method that gets data from the backend. Each request

**Problem**: I am unable to get the user to redirect to the home page, because  the following code does not run:

```
 vm.login = function() {      
        vm.error = '';

        Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
        .then(function(data) {
            Auth.getUser()
            .then(function(data) {
                vm.user = data.data;
            });

            if (data.success) {
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                vm.error = data.message;
                console.log(vm.error);
            }

        });
    }
```

I do not get redirected to the homepage, although I also do not get any message either in the dev console or my terminal.

When I check the local storage via the dev console, I do not have the token. However, I am able to login/signup/post data successfully using POSTMAN. I think the problem can be fleshed out via the following steps:

**1.** The user logs in, and the token is stored in the local storage
**2.** Auth.getUser() is suppose to request for the user data from the backend.
**3**.Each request requires the token to be verified via the jsonwebtoken.verify() method. 
**4**.For some reason, the token is not sent to my backend, so this does not run:

```
 api.use(function(req,res,next) {
        console.log('someone tried to access a secure page');

        var token = 
            req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

        if (token) {
       //code 


      } else {
         res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "No Token Provided"});
```

Here are what I deem the relevant files:

**backend:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../models/user.js');
var Story = require('../models/story.js');
var config = require('../../config/config.js');
var jsonWebToken = require('jsonwebtoken');
var sessionSecret = config.sessionSecret;


function createToken(user) {

    var token = jsonWebToken.sign({
        id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        username: user.username
    }, sessionSecret, {expiresInMinutes: 1440});

    return token;
}

module.exports = function(app, express) {
    var api = express.Router();


 api.post('/login', function(req,res) {

        User.findOne({username: req.body.username})
            .select('password').exec(function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                   if (!user) {
                       res.send('user does not exist!');
                   } else {
                       var isPasswordValid = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
                       if (!isPasswordValid) {
                           res.send('wrong password!');
                       } else {

                           var token = createToken(user);
                           res.json(
                               {success:true, 
                                message:'successfully logged in!', 
                                token: token});
                       }
                   }
                }
            })
        });


  api.use(function(req,res,next) {
        console.log('someone tried to access a secure page');

        var token = 
            req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

        if (token) {
           jsonWebToken.verify(token, sessionSecret, function(err, decoded) {

                if(err) {
                    res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "Failed to authenticate user"});

                } else {

                    //
                    req.decoded = decoded;
                    next();
                }
            });
        } else {
                   **//*****the message sent to my frontend*********
            res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: "No Token Provided"});
        }

    });

   api.get('/me', function(req,res) {
        res.send(req.decoded);
    })

    app.use('/api', api);
}
```

**frontend**:

**Angular factory:** retrieves data from the backend

```
var authService = angular.module('authService', []);

authService.factory('Auth', function($http, $location, $q, AuthToken) {


    var authFactory = {};

    authFactory.login = function(username,password) {

        return $http.post('/api/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }).success(function(data) {
            AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
            return data;         
        })
    }


    authFactory.getUser = function() {

       if (AuthToken.getToken()) {
           return $http.get('/api/me');
       } else {
           return $q.reject({message: 'unable to get data'});
       }
    }


    return authFactory;

});

authService.factory('AuthToken', function($window) {

    var authTokenFactory = {};

    authTokenFactory.getToken = function() {
        return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    authTokenFactory.setToken = function(token) {
        if (token) {
            $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        } else {
            $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
    }  
    return authTokenFactory;   
});

authService.factory('AuthInterceptor', function($q, $location, AuthToken) {

var interceptorFactory = {};


interceptorFactory.request = function(config) {

    var token = AuthToken.getToken();

    if(token) {

        config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
    }
    return config;


};

interceptorFactory.responseError = function(response) {
      if (response.status === 403) {
          $location.path('/login');
          return $q.reject(response);
      }
    }
});
```

**mainController**:

```
angular.module('MainController', [])

    .controller('mainController', ['$rootScope','$location','Auth', function($rootScope,$location, Auth) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLogged();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {

        vm.isLoggedIn = Auth.isLogged();
            Auth.getUser().then(function(data) {
                vm.user = data.data;
            })                              
        })


    vm.login = function() {      
        vm.error = '';

        Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
        .then(function(data) {
            Auth.getUser()
            .then(function(data) {
                vm.user = data.data;
            });

            if (data.success) {
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                vm.error = data.message;
                console.log(vm.error);
            }

        });
    }
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <base href="/">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
          <!--angular services  -->
        <script src="app/auth/authService.js"></script>
         <!--angular controllers  -->
        <script src="app/controllers/mainController.js"></script>

        <script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

**login.html**:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController as login">

    <form method="post" ng-submit="login.login()">  
       username:  <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="login.loginData.username">
       password:  <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="login.loginData.password">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>


    </form>
</div>
```

further code will be made available upon request. I will be truly grateful for any help as I have spent countless hours trying to solve this problem.

Comment: While `$http.get('/api/me');`, you are not sending any `token`

Comment: You can use [`Interceptors`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to send token in each `http request`

Comment: I thought I was sending tokens via  config.headers['x-access-token'] = token. Can you please elaborate on how to send tokens, if you have a different way?

Comment: You can find it out using your developers tools -> Network tab. Where are you setting token ? Have you written `interceptor` for that ? This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244809/angular-js-set-token-on-header-default

Comment: I forgot to include my interceptor! Please have a look at Angular Factory code again, it is at the bottom.

Comment: You forgot to push: `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor')` I suppose..

Comment: I could not simply add the line of code you wrote above, as I got the error that $httpProvider is not defined. So I followed [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018427/in-what-context-do-you-define-an-http-interceptor-in-angularjs[link] and it is still not working as I get the following error message:Unknown provider: $httpProviderProvider <- $httpProvider <- AuthInterceptor <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile.    Here is the code I wrote:

`authService.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
    
}]);
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98312/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-frosty619).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the redirection is happening before the getting the data:

```
vm.login = function() {      
    vm.error = '';

    Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
    .then(function(resp) {  // <------changed the arg to 'resp'
        Auth.getUser()
        .then(function(data) {
            vm.user = data.data;
            if (resp.success) { // <------put the condition here with 'resp'
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                vm.error = resp.message;
                console.log(vm.error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

---

Another change i can suggest you to use `.then()` instead of `.success()` here:

```
    return $http.post('/api/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }).then(function(data) {  // <--------change to `.then()`
        AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
        return data;         
    })
```

Comment: @Frosty619 can you confirm you are able to pass these `vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password` to the function.

Comment: If you look at the authFactory.login method under the angularFactory section, you will see that it returns data if the login is successful, and then I use AuthToken.setToken(data.token) to set the token into the local storage. Since I AM getting the token in my local storage, I guess it's safe to assume that I am able to the pass the login arguments to the function

Comment: This is a guess but i feel you have to return `interceptorFactory`.

Comment: you are right, I tried that, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: and can you try by changing the order of your factories? By putting the `AuthToken` above to `Auth`

Comment: You have used `.success()` in the `Auth` factory change it to `.then()`.

Comment: Tried both the suggestions above, still the same error.